# Android storing data locally for offline access

Tags: android, performance

In my project, there is a scenario where i am getting Json data as response when the device is in online. I need the same data when the device is offline.

I have tried saving the data into Default SharedPreference file using

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("contactobject", result.toString()).apply();
```

And retrieving the data from SharedPreference file like using

```
String result = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("contactobject", "");
```

The thing is, by using SharedPreference, the usage of memory is high.

Question : Is there any other better way to save the data in Cache memory as like WebView for better performance.

Answer (score 3):

The `Sharedpreferences` use key values.That might be create a problem some time. So store the data in database and retrieve  it when user is offline.

**UPDATE**
you can use database for retrieving records like this

```
 aQuery.progress(progressDialog).ajax(url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void callback(String url, JSONObject object, AjaxStatus status) {

        if (object != null) {
            //delete old records
            db.execSQL("delete from entrys");
            String quotos = object.optString("quote_data");
            String msg = object.optString("msg");
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg+" and "+quotos,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(quotos);
                al = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String str = jsonObject.getString("quote");
                    al.add(str);

                    //add the data in database
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name",str);
                    db.insert("entrys",null,cv);
                    Log.d("STR,","Created"+str);
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Wishes.this, R.layout.single_row, R.id.tv_wishdata, al);
                lv.setAdapter(adpt);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server is busy Reciving data..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            //show the data when user is offline
            SimpleCursorAdapter sd = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_row,c, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.tv_wishdata});
            lv.setAdapter(sd);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

**Option 2** You can also use cache files for retrieve data.
First of all create a function for save data in cachefile.

```
public  void saveMyData()
{
    try {
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),"")+"cachefile.txt"));
        out.writeObject(al.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then after retrieve data whenever you what to show data from file.

```
  private String retriveMyData()
{
    String fileContent = "";
    try {
        String currentLine;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+"cachefile.txt");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream,"UTF-8"));


        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent += currentLine + '\n';
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.d("FAILED","THOS IS NULL");
        fileContent = null;
    }
    Log.d("SUCESS","SUCESS BUDDYY"+fileContent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),fileContent+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return fileContent;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write the JSON to your cache dir. Read it from your cache file if you're offline and update your cache when you're online. You don't need a database for simple JSON. Seriously.